# Webgrid alternative layouts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting, paging, webgrid

Ok so this is my first question and I think it is a good one. I am wanting to layout a webgrid  in MVC 4 C# with a different format than a standard table. What I am looking for is a layout like [this example](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/olstemplatemapper.jsp?&id=pcat17071&type=page&ks=960&st=categoryid%24abcat0101001&sc=Global&cp=1&sp=-bestsellingsort%20skuidsaas&qp=tvscreensize_facet=TV%20Screen%20Size~60%22%20-%2064%22%5Etvscreensize_facet=SAAS~TV%20Screen%20Size~65%22%20and%20Up&list=y&usc=All%20Categories&nrp=15&fs=saas&iht=n&seeAll=&browsedCategory=abcat0101001)(bestbuy product list example).

I would like to use webgrid because of it's built-in paging and sorting capabilities. I can live with simpler solutions than the one I included but I need it to keep the same general format with a picture on the left and information in a list-like look on the right if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like three columns to me. All you need to do is pass in the appropriate HTML into the `format` parameter for each column: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridcolumn.format(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: I will give that a try and post how it turned out! thanks for the help!